# How to retrieve value from nested object?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im trying to get a value from nested parameter like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: myObject
    type: object
    default:
      foo: FOO
      things:
        - one
      nested:
        one: apple
        count: 3
```

So Im expecting to write smth like this `${{ parameters.myObject.foo }}` or `${{ parameters.myObject.nested.one }}` to retrieve a value.

Also there is an example of looping through list object like this:

```
- name: listOfStrings
  type: object
  default:
  - one
  - two

steps:
- ${{ each value in parameters.listOfStrings }}:
  - script: echo ${{ value }}
```

Thats why I tried to get value in such way but it doesn't work for me as well:

```
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
    foo: FOO
    nested:
      one: apple

steps:
- ${{ each value in parameters.myObject }}:
  - script: echo ${{ value.foo }}
```

Unfortunately Microsoft doesn't provide an example in doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops

Can somebody suggest how to retrieve nested value?

Answer (score 6):

The object contains nested object and array, you can use below code:

```
parameters:
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
    foo: FOO
    bar: BAR
    things:
    - one
    - two
    - three
    nested:
      one: apple
      two: pear
      count: 3

trigger: none

jobs: 
- job: object
  steps:
    - bash: echo ${{parameters.myObject.foo}}                     # echo object foo value
    - bash: echo ${{parameters.myObject.things[1]}}               # echo one specific string value in array.
    - bash: echo ${{parameters.myObject.nested.two}}              # echo nested object value
    - ${{ each value in parameters.myObject.things }}:            # echo every string value in array.
      - script: echo ${{ value }}
    - ${{ each pair in parameters.myObject.nested }}:             # echo every nested object key and value
      - script: echo "${{ pair.key }}, ${{ pair.value }}"
```

[image]

You have to specify nested object(parameters.myObject.nested) for "each" string, since you cannot convert object(array as well) to string for output.

Comment: Greetings @Serhiy Baglai, how is it going? Does it make sense to you?