# retrieve value from nested object parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

my question is closely releted to this one, but I this one doesnt seem to help me :( [How to retrieve value from nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772621/how-to-retrieve-value-from-nested-object)

I am trying to loop over an object that i get as a parameter, I use a default value as an example, the values in this object are also objects.

I have a template:

```
parameters: 
  - name: fruits
    type: object
    default:     
      - Banana:
          name: " acuminata"
          url: "www.banana.com/ acuminata"
      - Apple:
          name: "jonaGold"
          url: "www.apple.com"


steps:

- bash: echo ${{parameters.fruits[0].url}}    



- ${{ each fruit in parameters.fruits }}:
  - script: echo ${{fruit.name}}
```

Both the first bash and the second bash are not working. Is it possible to use objects in azure pipelines like this?

This is my output for both bash steps:
[image]

```
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8035586Z ##[section]Starting: CmdLine
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8178179Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8178533Z Task         : Command line
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8178874Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8179171Z Version      : 2.201.1
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8179614Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8179954Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2022-04-13T13:01:21.8180355Z ==============================================================================
2022-04-13T13:01:23.2732262Z Generating script.
2022-04-13T13:01:23.2840010Z Script contents: shell
2022-04-13T13:01:23.2849739Z echo
2022-04-13T13:01:23.3217106Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2022-04-13T13:01:23.3517504Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\7a91b1cc-432d-4a20-b39c-7c6b0c78724b.cmd""
2022-04-13T13:01:23.3655983Z ECHO is off.
2022-04-13T13:01:23.3990627Z ##[section]Finishing: CmdLine
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution. The other thread does provide an answer, I just need to read better :P.

You can access the values with the 'value' keyword. I also removed the '-' before the keywords so its not an array anymore. The code now looks like this:

```
parameters: 
  - name: fruits
    type: object
    default:     
      Banana:
        name: " acuminata"
        url: "www.banana.com/ acuminata"
      Apple:
        name: "jonaGold"
        url: "www.apple.com"


steps:
   

- ${{ each fruit in parameters.fruits }}:
  - script: echo ${{fruit.value.name}}
```

And I get this output:
[image]

I did not yet get the first one working, but i don't really need this for my project

```
- bash: echo ${{parameters.fruits[0].value.url}}
```